# Why does it show Black screen instead of background image

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and i've a issue.Thinking that I did all the steps correctly, I added a background image, but the emulator shows a black screen instead of the image.

[black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mKdi.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('/assets/images/login_bg.png'),
              fit:BoxFit.cover))
      ,
    );
  }
}
```

My code is also very simple. Is it trying to load but taking a long time?

Comment: Is this your main.dart?. Please share your main.dart code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the asset should be without the first slash. So like

```
AssetImage('assets/images/login_bg.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please improve your image path:**

```
AssetImage('/assets/images/login_bg.png')
```

**to**

```
AssetImage('assets/images/login_bg.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

The path for image should not start with "/"

```
AssetImage('assets/images/login_bg.png')
```

and also please try to return Scaffold and not container when building a widget

So Your code should be Like

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/login_bg.png'),
              fit:BoxFit.cover)),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to flutter and still trying to learn.

Comment: @İremYönet Your Welcome buddy... Welcome to stackoverflow... if the solution works for you then please upvote and accept the answer whichever answer works for you !!